# Whose spirit and whose lips are referred to in Psalms 106:33?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rashi, translation, tehilim-psalms, english

> 32וַיַּקְצִיפוּ עַל־מֵי מְרִיבָה וַיֵּרַע לְמֹשֶׁה בַּעֲבוּרָם ׃
>   33: כִּי־הִמְרוּ אֶת־רוּחוֹ וַיְבַטֵּא בִּשְׂפָתָיו׃
>
> 32: They provoked wrath at the waters of Meribah and Moses suffered on their account,
>   33: because they rebelled against Him and he spoke rashly.

Whose spirit and whose lips are referred to in Psalms 106:33: [Mechon Mamre's translation](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26a6.htm) says "... and he (Moses) spoke rashly with his lips" and [Chabad's translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16327/showrashi/true) says "For they rebelled against His (G-d's) spirit, and He (G-d) uttered with His lips?

My question is, what do our rabbis of blessed memory say?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed different Rabbis interpret it differently, hence the difference in translations, for the list of commentaries see [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.106.33?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en).

For example, Ebn Ezra: "כי המרו את רוחו - שב אל השם, כמו והמה מרו ועצבו את רוח קדשו.", also Metzudat David: "כי המרו. כי ישראל מרו בדבר ה׳‎:" but "ויבטא. ודבר משה בשפתיו לקרותם ממרים", also Rada"k "ויבטא בשפתיו. האל יתברך שלא יכנסו לארץ בעון זה:"

The Targum does not add clarity, but I've found the English [translation of the Sepuagiant](https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/chapter.asp?book=24&page=105) says Moses.

Comment: Is there a majority/minority opinion on this one?

Comment: We don't follow the majority on interpretations. All interpretations are equally valid as long as they are personal speculations.

Comment: if that is the case, then why do we sometimes appeal to the fact that such and such is of the majority/minority opinion?

Comment: Unlike the Halachah which we have to follow a single opinion (we can't follow two opposing opinions at once), the interpretations are impractical - you can interpret a verse anyway you like, there's no need to pick one true way of interpretation. I asked a question once" can there be a really wrong interpretation" (search for it) and the answer is No.

Comment: so in terms of a halachic question, we follow the majority opinion, whereas in terms of non-halachic question, there is no wrong answer?

Comment: Absolutely correct.